# In Blazor how do you load an image into memory so C# can access it

Tags: webapi, blazor-webassembly

I am sure this is something simple that I have missed, but I need to load an image from WASM Blazor from the webserver so that I can print it to a PDF file.  Printing isn't an issue.  I just need to load it into a memory stream or something I can convert to a memory stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug around long enough that I found the answer to this issue.  I was being stupid, but just in case someone needs to know the answer here it is:

```
public class DownloadBinFile 
{
    private HttpClient client;
    public DownloadBinFile(HttpClient http_)
    {
        client = http_;
    }
    public async Task<Stream> Download(string url)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{url}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Stream ms;
        ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return ms;
    }
}
```